# Ошибка в выполнении запроса SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

**Есть следующий запрос ->**

```
class HeroDaoPostgres(HeroDaoBase, PostgresDaoBase):

    async def find_by_id(self, hero_id: int, *args, **kwargs):
        async with self.async_session() as session:
            query = select(Hero).where(Hero.id == hero_id)
            result = await session.execute(query)
            return result
```

Который валится на переменной result. Выдает следующее:

```
ValueError: [TypeError("attribute of type 'RMKeyView' is not callable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

В чем проблема заключается?
в async_session лежит объект `sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)`

Comment: Валится на 6 строчке?

Comment: @AlecsFly, исправлено. сделал вот так  ```result = (await session.execute(query)).scalar()```